# Java bluetooth bluecove application

Tags: java, eclipse, bluetooth, 64-bit, bluecove

I'm working on a bluetooth java application under eclipse in OS X 10.10.1 Yosemite 64bit with the blue cove-2.1.0 jar. When I run the application I get the error message:

```
Native Library bluecove not available
```

Through a web search I found that the issue is caused by the 64 bit version of Java, but when I try to run the application with the -d32 argument passed to the VM I get the error:

```
Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.
```

Is there anyway to run this application despite the 64 bit configuration? or is there any other library despite bluecove that can manage a 64 bit environment?

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing happened to me with a different java application (jruby), around which I was able to work by resetting my `JAVA_HOME` to a JVM that supports 32-bit mode. Essentially your 64-bit JVM is trying to tell you that it won't run in 32-bit mode, even when you specify the `-d32` option.

To work around this, try running: `/usr/libexec/java_home -d32`

On my 64-bit Yosemite machine, that command returned `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_65-b14-462.jdk/Contents/Home`, which is the path to a JVM on my machine that will run in 32-bit mode. If you have one or more 32-bit-capable JVMs on your machine, you'll get a path to one of them, which you can then use to set your `JAVA_HOME` variable accordingly and you'll be off to the races.

If you don't have a 32-bit-capabile JVM on your machine, you will need to install one via the Oracle web site or homebrew and then set your `JAVA_HOME` accordingly.

If you want to skip a step or two, just do this -- `` export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -d32` `` -- which will automatically set your `JAVA_HOME` to the first detected instance of a JVM capable of running in 32-bit mode.